# Can't launch ipython after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: ipython, canopy, osx-elcapitan

Does anyone know how to undo the changes to paths and permissions wrought by upgrading to El Capitan.  Specifically, it appears that OS X is now using the system python instead of my Canopy installation.

These look ok:

```
Michaels-Mac-mini:~ mellis$ which python
/Users/mellis/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

Michaels-Mac-mini:~ mellis$ which ipython
/Users/mellis/bin/ipython
```

But trying to launch ipython fails:

```
Michaels-Mac-mini:~ mellis$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mellis/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/pyth on/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ipython==0.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete update of my installed Canopy packages including ipython seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept your own answer so the question will be quickly evident as answered.

Comment: SO won't allow me to do that for 2 days.